# First child grow width of content until parent boundary invokes overflow ellipses

Tags: html, css

So a quick visual of what I'm trying to accomplish wherein the (gray) parent container is of variable width. The first child (red) is of variable auto width depending on its content until second child (green) reaches the end of the parent width wherein text-overflow: ellipses needs invoked on the first child (red) and the second child (green) always remains on the right of its sibling.

So first image example is if text isn't long enough to consume full width of parent. Second image is example of desired effect when first parent child does consume full width of parent container cell + width of sibling div.

[image]

The problem I keep running into no matter what I try between attempts using `inline-block` and `flex` on the child divs is that either it forces wrapping, the ellipses isn't displayed for overflow, or it tries pushing the parent passed 100% width. Notice no horizontal scrollbar should be necessary and table should invoke boundary at 100% width of the window, yet it does not...

The task is simple if the second child remains fixed to the right but how can I make the red box auto width until it reaches the containing parents end and then invoke overflow while keeping the green child on the right of it's sibling?

Quick example of the struggle (Notice green child is consumed by overflow:hidden and no longer visible in first cell);

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  border: gray 1px dotted;
  text-align: left;
  height: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipses;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div {  
  border: red 3px dashed;
  min-width: 3rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipses;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: rgba(red, .2);  
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipses;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  border: green 3px dashed;
  background-color: rgba(green, .2);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div>
          Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing  
        </div>
        <div>
          Blah
        </div>
      </th>
      <th style="width: 300px">
        <div>
          Another COLUMN
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Apologies if this is a duplicate but I couldn't find anything specific to this scenario. Both child divs would sit in a table cell if that helps description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with flexbox like below:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  border:2px solid;
  width:500px;
}
.container > div:last-child {
  width:100px;
  border:2px solid green;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
.container > div:first-child { 
  border:2px solid red;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>some text</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh ffs, I was using the shrink/grow method incorrectly. Thanks for the slice of humble pie!

Answer (score 1):

If you apply `display: flex` to the container to align the items side-by-side, you could then apply `flex-shrink: 0` to the green child to be sure that it maintains its size as the red div expands.

```css
div.container { 
  display: flex;
}

div.div1 {
  border: 2px solid red;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.div2 {
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">
    test test test 
  </div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">
    test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test
  </div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `table-layout: fixed` so your table uses 300px for 'Another Column' and the remaining space (100% - 300px) for the first two columns.
2. Use the correct value for `text-overflow` (`ellipsis` not `ellipses`)
3. Set the first `th` to `display: flex` and remove `height: 1rem` which truncates the contents of the cell.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

th {
  border: gray 1px dotted;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div {  
  border: red 3px dashed;
  min-width: 3rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipses;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: rgba(red, .2);  
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  border: green 3px dashed;
  background-color: rgba(green, .2);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="flex">
        <div>
          Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing  
        </div>
        <div>
          Blah
        </div>
      </th>
      <th style="width: 300px">
        <div>
          Another COLUMN
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```